# convert a curl request to php-curl - different responses received

Tags: apache, curl, php-curl

I have this request to update a user using the user provisioning API in owncloud.

```
curl -X PUT https://example.com/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users/pinuccio -d 'key=email' -d 'value=jack@google.com' -H "OCS-APIRequest: true" -u 'admin:adminpwd'
```

I am trying to convert it to PHP CURL.

I ended up so far with this:

```
$username = 'admin';
$password = 'adminpwd';
$postData = array(
    'key' => 'email',
    'value' => 'jack@google.com'
);

$ch = curl_init('https://thesmartred.com/cloud/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users/'.$userid);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, "OCS-APIRequest: true");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

but I get a 997 response. While if I run this on shell I get a 405. Why do I get two different answers?
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are couple of differences between your commandline request and php curl request.

First, You are using `CURLOPT_HEADER` in a wrong way. In [php curl manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) it says

> CURLOPT_HEADER    TRUE to include the header in the output

So to add a header in a proper way, example is:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'OCS-APIRequest: true'
));
```

Second, you are passing the array to your post fields. For array it does a `multipart/form-data` post. You need to pass data as string, and [http_build_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) comes handy this case.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));
```

Comment: many many thanks. on the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS you finally managed to explain me how it works. Really appreciate your support